# FFmpeg always in onProgress state OnSuccess/onFailure never called Android

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

Here is my command code of Android

```
try {
    String cmd[] = new String[]{"-i", video_file, "-ss", "00:04:00", "-i", audio_file, "-c:v", "copy", "-af", "apad", "-shortest", image.getPath()};

    ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new FFmpegExecuteResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onSuccess: " + message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgress(String message) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProgress: "+message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStart: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.e(TAG, "onFinish: ");
        }
   });
} catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried it long before for compressing videos and it took nearly 10 min for the total process to complete for a video which was having size of around 20mb size.

Answer (score 1):

You can try put

> -y

to the beginning of the ffmpeg command line.
Because ffmpeg doesn't overwrite the existing file or file path.
Example:

```
"-y -i..."
```